# Strange rendering issues IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

i've got an `sporadically` issue with the rendering in `IE11`.

I'ts also pretty hard to describe what actually happens it seems to overlay the background image on some parts of the site. The funny thing hovering an element displays that actual item how it supposed to look like. And not every time just some times.

Did someone else ever discovered this kind of issue? Any solutions?

[Link to the Website](http://www.bischoff-wil.ch/de/schulmaterial/shop)

Image:

[image]

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Too much reliance on `display:`table` and the like?

Comment: Please provide an example code and not a link to your website. This question won't be relevant after you'll change/fix/remove your website. By the way, I don't see this problem in my IE11 nor older IE versions.

Comment: @ItayGal my biggest problem is i really don't know where this issue is coming from. I'cant provide example code in this case.

Comment: @Mario make a copy of your page, then, start removing unnecessary code until you can provide the menu itself and the relevant css. If you do so, there is a good chance you'll even find your problem. As for now, the problem does not appear in my browser so that's almost impossible to solve it.

Comment: @ItayGal The problem is this issue doesn't appear always someday its there than a week not. It really has something to do with the IE rendering. Stripping unnecessary stuff doesn't help if i can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: How is it possible to solve a problem if it cannot be reproduced? Just an image of the problem is not enough. If the problem is in the HTML or CSS it must be consistent. If it's not, your problem might be coming from your dynamic content.

Comment: You might be running into a bug in your webpage (seems unlikely), in IE rendering engine or in your display driver.  I highly doubt you'll find any reprieve here on Stack Overflow.

My recommendation is to try to reproduce this issue on different hardware, then on a different version on IE, then on a different browser.  

If you find that it's not related to your page, your only way forward is to try to tweak your markup to remove the problematic combination.  Once you find something that causes the bug to disappear, there's a basis for your workaround.

Comment: @ItayGal It is possible to solve a problem that cannot be reproduced (think plane crashes).  It's just that it's a lot more difficult :)

Comment: @DanielS. Not exactly true, in plane crashes you have the broken pieces and the plane blue prints. Can you find fix a problem in a plane only by looking at a picture of the crashed plane? We can guess what's the problem is, but it's not the way problem are being solved here. He needs to extract the problematic code and provide it so we can see all the parts that affect his menu.

Comment: If the issue comes only sometimes - ask yourself - what changes sometimes? I see a page with products which seems dynamic - isnt there something that just breaks your html sometimes? (so it gets missunderstood)

Answer (score 5):

Please add this meta Tag to your HTML Header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Still same problem, didn't fixed the issue.