# Specific IE11 displays website strange (perhaps floats, and positioning)

Tags: html, css, rendering, internet-explorer-11

I have a (probably) sporadic problem with IE11. The website displays very strange in a client's client browser.

Problem: http://lab.krasfrielink.nl/uploads/Schermafbeelding%202014-09-23%20om%2010.07.31.png

Should be: http://reclame.studiopothoff.nl/contact/algemene-voorwaarden/

The problem seems very similar to this question, which has no answer yet: [Strange rendering issues IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337140/strange-rendering-issues-ie11).

I can't simulate the issue in IE11 in Win8.1 and 7.
The clients runs IE 11.0.9600 on Win8.1

Comment: did you check if the site is not added in the "compatibility settings" ?

Comment: Just did, good suggestion, But that's not it...

Comment: that's a bit weird, I'm actually using the same IE version 11.0.9600.17107 on Win 7. It can't be anything operating system related because this is purely a browser issue. I've had a similar issue with this and if you've added the IE meta tag and you've `Cntrl + Refreshed(F5)` and nothing changed, then I have no clue sorry. But if there is an answer I will learn from this.